# Config Server shows 'spring.profiles' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile'

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm upgrading our config server to Spring Boot 2.7 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.7.

In the bootstrap.yml I have this setting set to true:

spring.config.use-legacy-processing

This setting seems to clear up the warnings related to bootstrap.yml and application.yml, but it does NOT clear up the warnings related to the configuration files that it reads (i.e. the ones external to the application that are using spring.profiles).

Is there a way to tell it to "use-legacy-processing" for those files as well?